Help identify the fan like structure on the Ju-88 A4

The Nazi Ju-88 A4 has a fan or turbine like structure at the top mid section of the plane (seen at bottom center of the image) I'd like to know its purpose and Identify it.
GremlinWranger has answered the question and would like to thank you to all

It may be helpful if you could more clearly identify exactly what in the image you're referring to as the "fan or turbine like structure". Can you edit the image to draw an arrow on it, pointing to what you're interested in?

If it is the item at this question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/38281/60886 this is possibly a duplicate, though the question there is JU-87

In addition of the link provided by @GremlinWranger: the wheel-shaped part behind the glass is the sense antenna of  a direction finder. The directional antenna is below the sense antenna (not visible). Well explained in this video
